# How to reference the path to a compiled Webpack pack file from inside a JS file in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I am using the `webpacker` gem (version 4.0.7) for a Rails 6 RC2 app, and I am also using `serviceworker-rails` middleware gem (version 0.6.0) to integrate Service Worker with Rails.

Now, I want to create a `serviceworker.js` pack file (which I copied over and modified from `serviceworker-rails` [README](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails/blob/master/README.md) file) so that it can be served by Webpack and be routed using `serviceworker-rails` middleware.

So, in `app/javascript/packs/serviceworker.js.erb` (with `erb-loader` installed), I did this:

```
function onInstall(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '<%= asset_pack_path "application.js" %>',

        '<%= asset_pack_path "application.css" %>',

        '/offline.html',

      ]);
    })
  );
}

...
```

Doing this will cause Webpack to fail to compile the Service Worker pack as I cannot use `asset_pack_path` in pack files (one cannot get the path of the compiled pack before it is even compiled). So the question is, how do I reference the path to the compiled JS and CSS pack in my Service Worker script so that Service Worker can cache those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after digging deep for so long, I found the solution from this [issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1117) on GitHub (and also realized that I didn't read and understand the error properly as the error was `undefined method 'asset_pack_path'` and has nothing to do with compilation whatsoever). The problem was fixed by simply doing:

```
function onInstall(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([

        <% helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers %>

        '<%= helpers.asset_pack_path "application.js" %>',

        '<%= helpers.asset_pack_path "application.css" %>',

        '/offline.html',

      ]);
    })
  );
}

...
```

Comment: Let's say i want to directly assign an img source via javascript. Is there anyway i can resolve that image path without a view action helper?